# How to tell what line is what in R plots

Tags: r, plot, graph, time-series, xts

I currently have some time series data and I am plotting it.

When I plot it, each different line comes up in a different color, this is good however I do not know which color corresponds to which set of data.

Below is some of my data and the graph that is showing up.

`head(dbtw)
                    NSW1.Price     Coal      Gas    Hydro       PV    Solar     Wind
2018-01-01 10:30:00   71.34571 71.07403 89.78488 80.62076 75.73009 76.06731 71.07516
2018-01-08 10:30:00   69.84917 75.57009 90.70968 85.53869 81.16248 81.35853 74.72455
2018-01-15 10:30:00   73.28426 71.11159 84.50934 79.76321 73.85233 73.46695 67.40529
2018-01-22 10:30:00   73.53699 83.50025 93.42689 95.70735 93.25567 93.78646 80.18604
2018-01-29 10:30:00   85.63705 81.84558 92.62425 92.18889 92.76306 92.07045 78.42529
2018-02-05 10:30:00   72.72682 72.26647 86.09123 81.15528 75.74744 76.10385 68.83338`

When I type `plot(dbtw)` this is what comes up:

[image: time-series plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addLegend`, but the trick is that you need to specify `lty` or `lwd`.  This is because:

- `addLegend` is essentially a wrapper around `legend`
- `help(legend)` tells us that `lty, lwd   the line types and widths for lines appearing in the legend. One of these two must be specified for line drawing.`
- A quick dive into the source code for `addLegend` (`View(addLegend)` in `RStudio`) tells us that it does not specify either of these.

To wrap up a long story.  Here is a reprex:

```
library(xts)
data("anscombe", package = "datasets")
ans6 <- xts(anscombe[, 1:6], order.by = as.Date("2008-01-01") + 1:nrow(anscombe))

## Will NOT have the line colors
plot(ans6)
addLegend()
```

[image]

```
## Will have the line colors
plot(ans6)
addLegend(lty = 1)
## addLegend(lwd = 1) # this would also work
```

[image]